# Asking for Credentials, when requesting shared folders on the server, regularly for domain users?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, credentials

In our network, single domain controller, when some users (members of the domain) request shared folders on the server they are required to enter their credentials, 
the server is Windows Server 2008 R2, even checking to remember my credentials doesn't work,

sometimes it shows this message: "The system has detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you", sometimes it shows different messages,

it happens more when the electricity is off, and the UPS powers is used all of it and after is Server is ready it is shown to some users,
note: electricity problems happen a lot here !!

when I try to recreate the case sometimes I failed,
I searched Google for it, I didn't find useful results, some talk about kerberos, but we don't use kerberos,

this keeps going each day or two, 
how to overcome this, I don't want these messages to appear to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I solved it,
the DNS of the clients was not set to the IP of the server, when I changed the IP of the DNS server in the client configuration the problem has gone.

Answer (score 2):

This question was discussed before at social. technet. Refer to this link.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/de1edad4-964f-4e6b-ac0e-adbb273581fd/

And further more read this blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/01/22/vista-remote-desktop-connection-authentication-faq.aspx

As this is a server issues and so there nothing connection of electricity with the error message. Please check out your services at the network.

Comment: I don't think their question is about remote desktop.

Comment: it was a DNS problem in the client, there were not set with the IP of the Domain Controller, when I changed the DNS Server in the clients to the IP of our DC, it has been solved